# How can I use sed or grep to delete the first line of input if it contains a string?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am redirecting input and have 2 fields that I extracted from the tail of an XML file, and I need to ignore the first line if it isn't the first of the 2 entries.

`tail -n 327 ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel | grep -e "<bookmark href=" -e "<mime:mime-type type="`

Here is the output from that code, which is working fine, but the problem is that the first line is a

```
<mime:mime-type type="application/x-shellscript"/>
<bookmark href="file:///usr/local/bin/menu_manager.sh" added="2019-09-17T08:33:48Z" modified="2019-09-17T08:33:48Z" visited="2019-09-17T08:33:49Z">
<mime:mime-type type="application/x-shellscript"/>
```

I need to look at the first line, and if it contains the string 
`<mime:mime-type type=`
then I need to remove that line and pass the rest of the  lines on for the next processing step

I tried 
`sed '1/<mime:mime-type/d'`

```
But is gives me an error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `/'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```sh
sed '1{/<mime:mime-type/d}'
```

which uses a block `{}` which is only run on line 1, with the delete command in the block.

Comment: Maybe explain how `1` and `/regex/` are both address expressions, and how the curly block allows you to have more than one address expression.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with `awk` you can use this

```
awk 'NR!=1 || !/<mime:mime-type type=/'
```

This prints every line that is not the first line (`NR!=1`) or doesn't match the pattern (`!/<mime:mime-type type=/`). As there is no action specified, `awk` uses the default action `print`.

Comment: Beat me to it! I'd coded the condition as `awk '!(NR == 1 && /<mime:mime-type/)'` but otherwise identical